# Selenium C# - NoSuchElementException passing CssSelector into method

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to pass a CssSelector into a custom wait method but I'm struggling to figure out why it can't find the element.

This is the CssSelector on BasePage.cs

```
public IWebElement ValidationErrorsPopup => Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class='_100 bigpad']"));
```

And this is my custom method within WebElementExtensions.cs

```
public static void WeElementsLocatedByCssSelector(this IWebElement element, int sec = 10)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Browser(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.CssSelector(element.ToString())));
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

And then I call it within BasePage.cs and pass in as so:

```
ValidationErrorsPopup.WeElementsLocatedByCssSelector();
```

If I simply just pass in the CssSelector then this works however when I try to pass in an element as string it doesn't seem to like it.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you trying to pass it as a `string`...?  Aren't you calling it an `IWebElement` in the methods signature?

Comment: Yes but if i try and pass it in as IWebElement as intended I receive 'cannot convert IWebElement to string' which is why I tried to pass it in as a string instead.

Comment: What about calling `element.ToString()`?

Comment: As soon as I remove ToString() from the method and try to pass in 'element' as an IWebElement that's when we get the conversion error so it as not an option. In any case, I've tried to convert the element to string directly and that also resulted in an error. So confused!

Comment: [This](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26375/how-to-convert-webelement-to-string-in-selenium-using-java), perhaps?  Granted the example is in `Java` but, that isn't too hard to convert to `C#`.